# gRPC server within a WPF desktop application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, grpc

I'm currently playing around with gRPC and have so far created a simple C# hello world demo, using a Visual Studio `ASP.Net Core gRPC Service` project as the server, and a client console app.

What I'd like to do next is have the gRPC server running within a .Net 6 WPF desktop app (call it "AppA"), allowing another desktop app ("AppB") to make requests for information from AppA. Is this even possible?

Normally I would use WCF for this, but I was warned off CoreWCF due to its immaturity.

Comment: The managed server of gRPC is based on ASP.NET, so really this is: "can a process be both an ASP.NET server, and a WPF host"; I don't know the answer to that, but it is an intriguing question! However, I would have questions here - in particular, around why WPF is the *server* and not the *client* in this scenario. Would it perhaps make more sense to have a separate server part, that both AppA and AppB talk to as clients? Note that the *unmanaged* gRPC server is probably a lot easier to hook here, but the unmanaged gRPC core is marked end-of-life now

Comment: @MarcGravell the idea of making the gRPC server a "middle-man" did cross my mind, but this would of course be a more complex solution than if the server was part of the WPF app where it could reference the types needed to handle client requests. I assume gRPC does support this middle-man approach, with the server somehow being able to forward requests (and their responses) back and forth between two clients?

Comment: that isn't an inbuilt scenario, as in the general case you'd need to think about what that means in terms of N clients; however, it is certainly one that you can orchestrate pretty easily once you've figured out what those rules are; you'd presumably set up a duplex pipe on each, and use something like a `Channel<T>` or similar as an intermediary

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to host a gRPC service from within a WPF desktop app.

The project needs to reference the "Grpc.AspNetCore" package (no "proto" stuff, you'll see why later).

Then, there's the code to start the web application. For the purposes of my demo app I implemented this in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private WebApplication? _app;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Task.Run(() => StartServer());
}

private void StartServer()
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

    // Despite adding a "launchSettings.json" file to the project, I couldn't find a way 
    // for the builder to pick it up, so had to configure the URLs here:
    builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://*:5219", "https://*:7219");

    builder.Services.AddGrpc();

    _app = builder.Build();
    _app.MapGrpcService<TestService>();
    _app.Run();
}

private void MainWindow_OnClosing(object? sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    _app?.StopAsync();
}
```

The call to _app.Run() blocks (until the web application stops), hence why I call StartServer() on a b/g thread.

I found an article stating that the proto compiler doesn't work properly in a WPF project. Although it was generating the classes, build errors indicated that these could not be found.
The solution was to add the "protos" stuff and service classes to a class library instead, then reference this from the WPF "server". The class library project needed to reference the following packages:

- Google.Protobuf
- Grpc.AspNetCore
- Grpc.Tools